# PHP Contact form fail

Tags: php, html, forms

I've written a php contact form and can't figure out why it is not sending an email. The form submits fine but doesn't send an actual email.

The below is my PHP code.

```
<?php  
 //If the form is submitted  
 if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {  

     //Check to make sure that the name field is not empty  
     if(trim($_POST['contactname']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
        $name = trim($_POST['contactname']);  
     }  
     //Check to make sure that the subject field is not empty  
    if(trim($_POST['subject']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else {  
         $subject = trim($_POST['subject']);  
     }  

    //Check to make sure sure that a valid email address is submitted  
    if(trim($_POST['email']) == '')  {  
         $hasError = true;  
     } else if (!preg_match("/^[A-Z0-9._%-]+@[A-Z0-9._%-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i", trim($_POST['email']))) {  
         $hasError = true;
     } else {  
         $email = trim($_POST['email']);  
     }  

    //Check to make sure comments were entered  
     if(trim($_POST['message']) == '') {  
         $hasError = true;  
    } else {  
        if(function_exists('stripslashes')) {  
             $comments = stripslashes(trim($_POST['message']));  
       } else {  
            $comments = trim($_POST['message']);  
        }  
     }  

    //If there is no error, send the email  
     if(!isset($hasError)) {  
        $emailTo = 'xyz@xyz.com';  
        $body = "Name: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSubject: $subject \n\nComments:\n $comments";  
        $headers = 'From: My Site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email;  

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);  
       $emailSent = true;  
 }  
}  
?>
```

The HTML code below is the Contact form HTML:

```
 <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" id="contactform">
                <fieldset class="contact-fieldset">
                    <h2>Send us a message</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label for="contactname">Your Name:</label>
                            <div class="ctinput-bg"><input type="text" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="contact-input required" /></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="email">Email:</label>
                            <div class="ctinput-bg"><input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="contact-input required email" /></div>
                        </li>     
                        <li>
                            <label for="subject">Subject:</label>
                            <div class="ctinput-bg"><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" class="contact-input required" /></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label for="message">Your message:</label>
                            <div class="cttxtarea-bg"><textarea rows="6" cols="40" id="message" name="message" class="contact-textarea required"></textarea></div>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <div class="form-button contact-submit">
                                <span><input type="submit" value="&nbsp;&nbsp;send message&nbsp;&nbsp;" name="submit" /></span>
                            </div>
                        </li>                      
                    </ul>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: is there anything in the server error log?

Comment: Are you trying `mail()` function in your local server?

Comment: Do you have mail server installed that can actually do the sending? It's not that obvious for everyone :-)

Comment: I don't think i do have a mail server installed. I didn't realise i needed to install one???

Answer (score 1):

On top of the solutions others have provided I would highly recommend using the SwiftMailer library.

I had to create an automated email feature and it was a nightmare to manually set up the headers and such. SwiftMailer saved me a heap of time, see [here](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/messages.html) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `mail` function isn't set up properly. Check your `php.ini` file and ensure you have the correct SMTP server settings.

Also, unrelated to your original question, but I'm not sure that using `<ul>` to markup a form is semantically correct. A set of fields isn't really an unsorted list, I'd prefer to use a semantically-correct `<table>` or even a series of `<div>`s.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 things :

1- the declairation of $hasError = false in the top of your code (make shure it excist)

2 - Generate headers as this :

```
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Hope this will do the trick,

Answer (score 0):

You can try to check if the mail is actually send:

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} else {
   echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

And to be sure you can also do a var_dump of your headers to see if they are correct:

```
var_dump($headers);
```

These things won't solve the problem, but will surely help to debug it.